# if construction in sql 

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not good at t-sql, so I need help.

I have this code I wrote myself, but how write that I want I don't know (and sorry for English)

```
declare @questionid int
set @questionid = 22

declare @providerid int
set @providerid = 189

select [closed] into #question from [Data].[dbo].[Question] where [questionid] = @questionid  

-- and here, if [closed] is null I must write in the question table current date GETDATE()
UPDATE [Data].[dbo].[Question] SET [closed] = GETDATE() WHERE [questionid] = @questionid and [providerid] = @providerid

-- or, if [closed] is not null I must write there null
UPDATE [Data].[dbo].[Question] SET [closed] = null WHERE [questionid] = @questionid and [providerid] = @providerid

drop table #question
```

How can I do that?

Comment: its better to go for case when which is compact...and save extra line and make code clear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the temp table for this

```
declare @questionid int
set @questionid = 22

declare @providerid int
set @providerid = 189

declare @closed datetime
select @closed = [closed] from [Data].[dbo].[Question] where [questionid] = @questionid  

-- and here, if [closed] is null I must write in the question table current date GETDATE()
IF @closed IS NULL
    UPDATE [Data].[dbo].[Question] SET [closed] = GETDATE() WHERE [questionid] = @questionid and [providerid] = @providerid
ELSE
-- or, if [closed] is not null I must write there null
    UPDATE [Data].[dbo].[Question] SET [closed] = null WHERE [questionid] = @questionid and [providerid] = @providerid
```

I must say, I don't understand the logic you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Thanks, That is I need. @closed variable isnt bit, its Datetime. If user cliks on the Close button - Question will close, If user cliks on the same button (with another text "open") - question will open. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix variable declaration. Just for you to know, if you have more than one sentence inside the IF, you have to use BEGIN and END to enclose them. Also, it's possible in this case to use one single UPDATE without need of using an IF, as @PranayRana states, but as you were asking how to use IF to learn it's use, I answered with that.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `case when`  you can easily achieve your task..

```
UPDATE [Data].[dbo].[Question] 
SET [closed] = CASE
          WHEN [closed]  is null THEN GetDate()
          ELSE null
          END
WHERE [questionid] = @questionid 
   and [providerid] = @providerid
```

Comment: I must do the reverse operation also. Null to datetime and datetime to null. AlejoBrz gave the working code.